# Alteração na exibição de tags

Tags: debate, tags, layout

Notei hoje que foram feitas alterações no *layout* relativas às tags, conforme *prints* abaixo:

**Lateral:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Popover:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obviamente que alterações sempre visam melhorias. Quais foram as melhorias funcionais em relação ao *layout* anterior ou foram apenas melhorias visuais?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinceramente? Achei a opção do popover muito legal e intuitiva. Ela me dá acesso a ações e informações que eu jamais iria atrás, pois seria quebra de navegação do jeito que eu gosto. Então, eu consigo de maneira fácil e tranquila obter a wiki da tag, observá-la e ver, também, seu impacto na comunidade/o quanto a comunidade gosta ou não da tag. Eu achei a parte de ignorar estranha, mas também nunca a usei nem pretendo, não vejo sentido nisso (para o meu uso do site, pelo menos).

Saca só como é legal o popver, sem nem precisar interromper [minha leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2506/64969), eu posso pegar informações relevantes:

[image: popover da tag JavaScript]

E, não, não tenho opiniões sobre o menu lateral. Passou totalmente ignorado por mim

Comment: [screen2gif](https://www.screentogif.com/). Ele tem escondido a opção do novo layout, que acho melhor e mais intuitivo do que o layout padrão/inicial.